# Recycleview Renew onCreateView how can i do

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner on Android development and if user see F1(see the data) and then goto F2(change the data) and come back the F1(this data is old data) is not user form F2 change data
so i want to again the F1 data please help me

Error message

```
E/error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

I think maybe is mine Rel is not initialization
i dont know  please give me a Suggest

tab1:

```
Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
            fragment.change();
```

Fragment1

if use onLazyLoad is correct but when  i use "call" is null

```
public class Fragment1 extends BaseLazyFragment {

private String url = "http://211.22.XXX.XXX/xampp/";
private RecyclerView Re1;
private int page = 1,run=0;
private String user_id,phone,cookie;
private TextView text1,text2,text3;
private Context context;
private boolean isFirstLoad = false;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
public void onLazyLoad() {
    initData();
    isFirstLoad =true;
}
public void change(){
    Log.e("change",toString());
    initData();
    run =1;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    initView(view);
    context = view.getContext();
    if(isFirstLoad){
        initData();
    }
    return view;
}
private void initView(View view){
    Re1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Re1_tab1);
    GlobalVariable Account = (GlobalVariable)getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    user_id = Account.getUser_id();
    phone = Account.getPhone();
    cookie = Account.getCookie();

}

private void initData(){
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
            .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDeath()
            .build());
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(runTimerStop,400);
    if(cookie != null) {
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(runTimerStop);
    }
}
private Runnable runTimerStop = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        select(user_id);

       // dialog.dismiss();
    }
};

private void select(String id){
    try {
        String r = DBphp.DBstr(id,cookie,url);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(r);
        ArrayList<Rel_list> items = new ArrayList<Rel_list>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            items.add(new Rel_list(jsonData.getString("id"),jsonData.getString("product_name"),jsonData.getString("specification")
                    ,jsonData.getString("selling_price"),jsonData.getString("operations_center"),jsonData.getString("inventory"),jsonData.getString("pictuture_id"),jsonData.getString("ANS")));
        }

        RelAdapter SA = new RelAdapter(getContext(),items);

        Re1.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        Re1.setAdapter(SA);
        SA.setOnItemClickListener(new RelAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int i) {
              //  byte buff[] = new byte[125*250];
                ImageView im0 = view.findViewById(R.id.img_id);
                TextView te0 = view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
                TextView te1 = view.findViewById(R.id.t2);
                TextView te2 = view.findViewById(R.id.t3);
                TextView te3 = view.findViewById(R.id.t4);
                TextView te4 = view.findViewById(R.id.t5);
                TextView te5 = view.findViewById(R.id.t6);
                TextView te6 = view.findViewById(R.id.t7);
                TextView te7 = view.findViewById(R.id.t14);
                Intent intent= new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getContext(), shop_thing.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("user_id",user_id);
                bundle.putString("user_phone",phone);
                bundle.putString("cookie",cookie);
                bundle.putString("page", String.valueOf(page));
                bundle.putString("shop_id",te0.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("shop_product_name",te1.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("shop_specification",te2.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("shop_selling_price",te3.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("shop_operations_center",te4.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("shop_inventory",te5.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("picture_id",te6.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("love",te7.getText().toString());

                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
}
```

}
home
[image]
F1
[image]

Comment: is F1 and F2 same Activity, your problem is you init Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1(); fragment.change(); but doen't make any fragment transaction, it mean Fragment will not create. About that I recommend you try to get current instance of F1 instead of init it

Comment: Please attach when you show F1 and F2 code

Comment: my Picture like this home = tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4(Fragment + viewpager)

 tab1 = F1 F2 F3(tab1+ viewpager ) when user go tab2 change data then come back  the  tab1

Comment: when user tab1(F1) saw the data and goto tab2 change data then come back to tab1(F1)

Comment: i am in tab1  setUserVisibleHint  then   Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();   
                     fragment.change();   Sorry for my english.

Comment: It's hard to understand could you attach image about your UI

Comment: f1 goto f2   user see T1 then F2 and then come back

Comment: try to transfer `if(isFirstLoad){ initData(); }` from `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()` method

Comment: Sorry is error   i run to  change is didnt   found Rel  Do you have any way